# he has been engaged in a project teaching chemistry to students

Tags: subordinate-clauses

1. Tanmay Rath holds a Ph.D. in polymer chemistry from IIT Kharagpur, with post doctoral experience in nanomaterials research in eastern Asia. However, for the last three years, he has been engaged in a ***project** teaching chemistry to undergraduate engineering students* in Motihari, a small town in Bihar’s East Champaran district. https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/1200-faculty-in-rural-engineering-colleges-will-lose-jobs-by-month-end/article33956298.ece

In (1) above, does the italicized part tell us what the project is about?

...he has been engaged in a **project** ***which is about** teaching chemistry to undergraduate engineering students...*

If not, how would you understand the italicized part in (1)?

Comment: It works perfectly well as it stands. There is no need to spell it out.

Comment: You mean *teaching chemistry* is what is the project?

Comment: The sentence means that **the project is teaching chemistry to undergraduate ...**.etc